# (C#) Can't manage to make restrictions for moving Object

Tags: c#, game-physics, keyevent

I'm a beginner, don't blame. I'm currently coding a simple "pingpong" game in c#, just to practice a bit because this is my second week of learning this language.

I've tried to make keyevents now to make "picsSchlägerRechts" move up and down, which worked well, but I can't manage to make a "restriction" for it to not move out of my panel. any ideas?

```
private static bool conditionUP ;
    private static bool conditionDown ;


    private void frmPingPong_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        {
            if (!(picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y == 0 && picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y == 249)) {
                conditionDown = true;
                conditionUP = true;
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && conditionUP == true)
            {
                picSchlägerRechts.Location = new Point(picSchlägerRechts.Location.X, picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y - ms);
                

                    if (picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y == 0)
                    {
                        conditionUP = false;
                        
                    }

                
            }
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S && conditionDown == true)
            {
                picSchlägerRechts.Location = new Point(picSchlägerRechts.Location.X, picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y + ms);
                
                if (picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y == 298)
                {
                    conditionDown = false;
                  

                }
            }
```

Comment: what is `ms`? instead of doing == use something like `<= 0` and `>= 249`

Comment: sorry, forgot to include that, it's just my variable for the movementspeed.

Comment: if your movementSpeed is set to a variable that jumps past 0 it will never hit your condition of `== 0` just use `<= 0` instead and maybe even put logic that if the location minus the movement speed is less than 0 just set it to 0 instead.

Comment: The movementspeed always remains the same, there's not an issue with that.

Comment: @austinwernli, I've tried to change it to "<= 0" from "==0" but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this so that it checks to make sure that your Y does not go greater than or less than max/min y

```
private void frmPingPong_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var maxY = 298;
    var minY = 0;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
    {
        var newY = picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y - ms;

        if (newY < minY)
        {
            newY = minY;
        }
        picSchlägerRechts.Location = new Point(picSchlägerRechts.Location.X, newY);
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
    {
        var newY = picSchlägerRechts.Location.Y + ms;

        if (newY > maxY)
        {
            newY = maxY;
        }
        picSchlägerRechts.Location = new Point(picSchlägerRechts.Location.X, newY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you understand why this one works as it's checking for the use case of the new location value being greater than or less than the minimum and maximum instead of checking for that exact value.

Comment: I understood your code perfectly after re-reading it 2-3times.

Comment: But I still don't understand why my previous one didn't work.. well, doesn't matter now, I'll still use your version anyways ! :)